# Unable to change text emphasis using LocalContentAlpha in Material Design 3

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text, material-you, material-design-3

Currently, I am migrating one of my apps to Material Design 3 which is entirely written in Kotlin using Jetpack Compose.

While using Material Design 2, I was able to change the emphasis of the text using the code below.

```kotlin
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.medium) {
                Text(
                    text = "Hello, world",
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
                )
            }
```

However, the same code doesn't work for Material Design 3 and the text has the default emphasis. Also, I can't find the relevant function anywhere for Material Design 3. I would like to know if there is any official way to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "[Emphasis and content alpha](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material2-material3#m3_16)" section in the [Migrate from Material 2 to Material 3 in Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material2-material3#m3_16) details the API changes.

Material2:

```
import androidx.compose.material.ContentAlpha
import androidx.compose.material.LocalContentAlpha

// High emphasis
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.high) {
    Icon(…)
}
// Medium emphasis
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.medium) {
    Icon(…)
}
// Disabled emphasis
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.disabled) {
    Icon(…)
}
```

Material3:

```
import androidx.compose.material3.LocalContentColor

// High emphasis
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentColor provides MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface) {
    Icon(…)
}
// Medium emphasis
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentColor provides MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant) {
    Icon(…)
}
// Disabled emphasis
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentColor provides MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface.copy(alpha = 0.38f)) {
    Icon(…)
}
```

Answer (score 9):

`MaterialTheme.typography.h6` is from Material 2, which means you're using `Text` composable from Material 2 too.

Material 3 analog of `h6` is `MaterialTheme.typography.headlineSmall`.

Make sure you have correct imports of both `Text` and `MaterialTheme` - these should be imported from `androidx.compose.material3` package. Also make sure you provide a correctly imported theme, e.g. [here](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/69e9d862b5ffb321064364d7883e859db6daeccd/Jetchat/app/src/main/java/com/example/compose/jetchat/theme/Themes.kt#L108).

Wrong imports is the most common mistake when migrating to M3, so be patient with it.

Also note that `LocalContentAlpha` doesn't exists in M3, providing M2 version will have no effect on M3 views. You can compare how `Text` composable determines its color in [M2](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/d7cd8b83d52580db6d9c0a759123de8117d73f29/compose/material/material/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/Text.kt#L112) and in [M3](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/d7cd8b83d52580db6d9c0a759123de8117d73f29/compose/material3/material3/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/Text.kt#L110).

I'm not sure wether it's gonna be added later (it's alpha after all), or it's handled in some other way in M3, here's a workaround(which is not perfect for sure):

```
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentColor provides LocalContentColor.current.copy(alpha = 0.4f)) {
```

p.s. `LocalContentColor` needs to be imported from M3 too